# Using Makefile when building QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to learn how to build QGIS plugins (using Erik Westra's book *Building Mapping Applications with QGIS*), but am stuck on how to use *make* and Makefile.  I'm running this on Windows.

I've created the following Makefile:

```
PLUGINNAME = geometryInfo
PY_FILES = __init__.py geometryInfo.py 
EXTRAS = metadata.txt icon.png
UI_FILES = 
RESOURCE_FILES = resources.py

default: compile

compile: $(UI_FILES) $(RESOURCE_FILES)

%.py : %.qrc
    pyrcc4 -o $@ $<

%.py : %.ui
    pyuic4 -o $@ $<  

deploy: compile
    mkdir -p $(HOME)/.qgis2/python/plugins/$(PLUGINNAME)
    cp -vf $(PY_FILES) $(HOME)/.qgis2/python/plugins/$(PLUGINNAME)
    cp -vf $(UI_FILES) $(HOME)/.qgis2/python/plugins/$(PLUGINNAME)
    cp -vf $(RESOURCE_FILES) $(HOME)/.qgis2/python/plugins/$(PLUGINNAME)
    cp -vf $(EXTRAS) $(HOME)/.qgis2/python/plugins/$(PLUGINNAME)

clean:
    rm $(UI_FILES) $(RESOURCE_FILES)
```

Westra's book says to run it by 'typing make deploy in the command line'.  I've worked out that I need to download a 'make' application for this, and have downloaded GnuWin, and added it to my path as C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin.

But this throws errors.

First, I get

```
pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [resources.py] Error 2
```

I can overcome this if I create resources.py manually (but isn't that what the Makefile is supposed to do)?

Then, I get:

```
mkdir -p /.qgis2/python/plugins/geometryInfo
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make: *** [deploy] Error 1
```

I can overcome that by switching the slashes around to \, and taking out -p (which Windows doesn't recognise).  Then it will create the directory (but only once - if I try a second time, it complains that the directory already exists).

The next line is *cp -vf $(PY_FILES) $(HOME)/.qgis2/python/plugins/$(PLUGINNAME)*.  It doesn't like that ... perhaps I should change the code to Windows-like 'copy' instead of 'cp'?

But if I'm completely re-writing the Makefile and running half the processes manually, I can't help thinking I'm on the wrong track.

How should I be running the *make deploy* command when using Windows?

Comment: try installing cygwin so that you have a more unix like environment

Answer (score 1):

So it seems to work if I:

1. Download Make 3.81 from GnuWin
2. Set a path to Make in my environment variables
3. Download Cygwin, and use that to run *make* (Thank you, iant)
4. Delete all references to UI_FILES from my Makefile, because I had left UI_FILES blank and that was causing errors  (*missing destination file operand after 'C:/Users/Steve/.qgis2/python/plugins/geometryInfo'*)
5. Insert the full path to pyrcc4 in my Makefile

The Makefile is now:

```
PLUGINNAME = geometryInfo
PY_FILES = __init__.py geometryInfo.py 
EXTRAS = metadata.txt icon.png
RESOURCE_FILES = resources.py
TARGET = C:/Users/Steve/.qgis2/python/plugins/$(PLUGINNAME)

default: compile

compile: $(RESOURCE_FILES)

%.py : %.qrc
    C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/pyrcc4 -o $@ $<

deploy: compile
    mkdir -p $(TARGET)
    cp -vf $(PY_FILES) $(TARGET)
    cp -vf $(RESOURCE_FILES) $(TARGET)
    cp -vf $(EXTRAS) $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm $(RESOURCE_FILES)
```

I can't help thinking I've over-complicated this somehow!